# How to define the output type in MogoOperations aggregate function?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I'm working on the MongoOperations's aggregate function to do some kind of mid level query using Spring Data.
As defined in the documentation for aggregate() function:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoOperations.html#aggregate-org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Class-, the outputType shoud be

> outputType - The parameterized type of the returned list, must not be null.

But I am not sure, how should i define that class/ object.
Here is my query:

```
    ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MongoConfig.class);
    MongoOperations mongoOperation = (MongoOperations) ctx.getBean("mongoTemplate"); 

    AggregationOperation match = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("country").is("tigo"));
    AggregationOperation unwind = Aggregation.unwind("myDetails");
    AggregationOperation match2 = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("myDetails.type").is("health"));
    AggregationOperation sort = Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "myDetails.datetime");
    AggregationOperation limit = Aggregation.limit(1);

    Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(match, unwind, match2, sort, limit);
    System.out.println("Aggregation = "+aggregation);
    AggregationOutput output = mongoOperation.aggregate(aggregation, "gui_data", outputType);
```

The outputType is what i need to define. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Create a pojo class to where aggregations results will be mapped say type as Output. AggregationResults<Output> results = mongoOperation.aggregate(aggregation, "gui_data", Output.class);  List<Output> outputList = results.getMappedResults();

Comment: Fine, But how will i get the result content/data? Implementation of Output class is what i want to know. I am not sure about the fields and datatypes of the result data. How to map content then?

Comment: Contents are mapped automatically. Well you have to first figure what you are expecting from result and then create a pojo to match those variables. Here are some examples docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation.supported-aggregation-operations

Answer (score 0):

i tried dto class so it will be useful to map that return values to that dto class

Comment: set the return values to the particular dto class,where ur fields are there in dto class.so the output type of the aggregation should be ur dto class,thanks for the comment,hope u understand and it will help u...return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "employee", EmployeeDTO.class).getMappedResults();